# discord.js "member is undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm attempting to filter out bot accounts that advertise on my server by banning usernames that join with the "discord.gg" username.

However it keeps returning error "member is undefined"

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('online');
})

client.on("message", async message => {
  if (member.user.username.includes("discord.gg")) {
    member.ban({days:7,reason:"Advertising."})
      .then(() => console.log(`Banned ${member.displayName}, ${m}`))
      .catch(console.error);
}
});
client.login(process.env.token);
```

Comment: Seems like you indeed haven't defined `member`. You are probably meant to get the member from the `message` parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use this

```js
if (member.user.username.includes("discord.gg")) {
    member.ban({days:7,reason:"Advertising."})
      .then(() => console.log(`Banned ${member.displayName}`))
      .catch(console.error);
}
```

in a scope where `member` is defined.

One way to do this would be to listen to the `guildMemberAdd` event instead of the `message`
For example:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
  if (member.user.username.includes("discord.gg")) {
    member.ban({days:7,reason:"Advertising."})
      .then(() => console.log(`Banned ${member.displayName}`))
      .catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

This would ban any member whose username includes `discord.gg` as soon as they join the server.

Otherwise you could just modify your current code like:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.member.user.username.includes("discord.gg")) {
    message.member.ban({days:7,reason:"Advertising."})
      .then(() => console.log(`Banned ${member.displayName}`))
      .catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

But this would error if a user sends the bot a direct message (`message.member` is undefined if there is no guild)

To counteract that you could also check if the message was sent in a guild with

```js
if (message.guild) {
  /* rest of the code */
}
```

Comment: Is `member, guild` supposed to be in that order?

Comment: My bad, the guild parameter isnt sent for this event